# How to get name of TCL test from the test itself

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I was wondering how you would find the name of the test you're running in tcl from the test itself? I couldn't find this on google.

I'm calling another proc and passing the name of the test that is calling it, as an argument. So I would like to know which tcl command can do that for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... can you provide some code of what you are running and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: I`m calling a proc from a test case. As an input to the proc, I`m passing in a parameter. That parameter is the name of the test case that called the proc. So what command in TCL gives u the name of the test you`re calling the proc from? Sry I can't provide code due to privacy, but that is all there is to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an encouraged use case… but you can use `info frame 1` to get the information if you use it directly inside the test.

```
proc example {contextTest} {
    puts "Called from $contextTest"
    return ok
}

tcltest::test foo-1.1 {testing the foo} {
    example [lindex [dict get [info frame 1] cmd] 1]
} ok
```

This assumes that you're using Tcl 8.5 or later, but Tcl 8.5 is the oldest currently-supported Tcl version so that's a reasonable restriction.

Comment: This will also work with the other styles of `tcltest::test` call; all put the test name as the first argument.

Comment: This doesn`t work for me, it returns the entire file path, is there another way? I'm using tcl 8.5.4

Comment: You're not calling it from _inside_ the test case.

Comment: Ok, is there another way of doing it?

Comment: This is what I get as output: source [pSet file] instead of my test name. Do you know where the problem could be?

Comment: @Ken Check out the slightly extended instrumentation shown in my answer. I assume what you perceive is due to the way you source/ execute your tests.

Answer (score 1):

I read your comments ("source ... instade of my test name") as follows: You seem to `source` the Tcl script file containing the tests (and Donal's instrumented tcltest), rather than batch-running the script from the command line: `tclsh /path/to/your/file.tcl`  In this setting, there will be an extra ("eval") stack frame which distorts introspection.

To turn Donal's instrumentation more robust, I suggest actually walking the Tcl stack and watching out for a valid tcltest frame. This could look as follows:

```
package req tcltest

proc example {} {
    for {set i 1} {$i<=[info frame]} {incr i} {
        set frameInfo [info frame $i]
        set frameType [dict get $frameInfo type]
        set cmd [dict get $frameInfo cmd]

        if {$frameType eq "source" && [lindex $cmd 0] eq "tcltest::test"} {
           puts "Called from [lindex $cmd 1]"
           return ok
        }
    }

    return notok
}

tcltest::test foo-1.1 {testing the foo} {
    example
} ok
```

This will return "Called from foo-1.1" both, when called as:

```
$ tclsh test.tcl 
Called from foo-1.1
```

and

```
$ tclsh
% source test.tcl
Called from foo-1.1
% exit
```

The Tcl version used (8.5, 8.6) is not relevant. However, your are advised to upgrade to 8.6, 8.5 has reached its end of life.