# How to get name of test file from within test file in TCL

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How do you get the name of the test file a test is being run from within the test? I couldn't seem to find the answer to this after checking Google. To clarify:

```
test mytest-1.1 {
   my test tests ... 
} -body {
    # Command to get name of file we're currently in.
} -result 0
```

I went to get the name of the .test file I'm currently in where the comment is.

Note: this is not a duplicate question, as I'm not wanting the name of the test, rather the name of the test file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get name of TCL test from the test itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995647/how-to-get-name-of-tcl-test-from-the-test-itself)

Comment: Please see my edits, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: It is widely redundant, once you have read the documentation ;) But, strictly, not a duplicate, agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slight extension to what is already covered in [How to get name of TCL test from the test itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995647/how-to-get-name-of-tcl-test-from-the-test-itself). Study the [`info frame` documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm#M17) and watch out for the `file` record of source-type frames:

```
[dict get $frameInfo file]
```

The extended example:

```
package req tcltest

proc example {} {
    for {set i 1} {$i<=[info frame]} {incr i} {
    set frameInfo [info frame $i]
    set frameType [dict get $frameInfo type]
    set cmd [dict get $frameInfo cmd]

    if {$frameType eq "source" && [lindex $cmd 0] eq "tcltest::test"} {
        puts $frameInfo
        puts "Called from [lindex $cmd 1] defined in '[dict get $frameInfo file]'"
        return ok
    }
    }

    return notok

}

tcltest::test foo-1.1 {testing the foo} {
    example
} ok
```

### Update

For the purpose of printing out the currently, innermost evaluated (`source`'d) file alone, you may also just call [`[info script]`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm#M38) or use the frame info obtained from `[info frame 0]` from within the test body.

```
tcltest::test foo-1.1 {testing the foo} {
    puts [info script]
    # puts [dict get [info frame 0] file]; # context dependent
} ok
```

Comment: So would I need to create an entire proc and step through a loop just to get the name, or is there a one line command (correct me if I'm wrong, but if I just use " set frameInfo [info frame $i]" followed by "[dict get $frameInfo file]")

Comment: Thanks for the edit mrcalvin, although I'd like to point out info script gives the full path to the file and the info frame 0 line gives the following error: key "file" not known in dictionary. So if you could provide some input as to this issue I would choose this answer.

Comment: If anyone knows the answer, please let me know as I really can't figure it out.

Comment: @Ken `[info frame]` is dependent on the calling (or, activating) context, similar as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995647/how-to-get-name-of-tcl-test-from-the-test-itself: explicit `source` vs. implicit sourcing (via `tclsh`). `info script` is agnostic about this because the script under evaluation is directly registered with the current interpreter.

Comment: ... so just use `[info script]` from within the test body or, alternatively, `[dict get $frameInfo file]` when using a dedicated introspection command such as `example` ... but not both, to avoid misunderstandings.